# Is there a way to know how much space mysqldump would need?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to know how much disk space a  `mysqldump` output would need?

This is to ensure that the target disk for the output has "enough space" before the *actual* call to `mysqldump`

Answer (score 0):

If running some unix flavor (linux, *bsd, etc) you can use `du -h` command to check the size the directory of the MySQL database that you want to dump. It should give you insight about how much space the dump will need, the dump will be smaller than the space used by the database

In my CentOS 7 box MySQL databases live in `/var/lib/mysql`, something like `du -hc /var/lib/mysql/somedb` should work